# Performance impact of flatten and reduce - without intermediary list creation

Tags: scala, caching

Given the following code:

```
def findMinOpt(li: List[Option[Int]]): Option[Int] =
    {
      val listwithoutOptions = li.flatten
      listwithoutOptions.reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
    }
```

It filters out all options effectively creating a new list and then returns the minimum.

The problem I see with this code is that it processes a list twice but in fact is worse than that as a second list is created which isnt cached. Is there an idiomatic way of processing the list just once?

Optional Question: How would one perform a benchmark? Usually OS uses caching mechanism so in between a repetition of a test I'd like to clear that cache up. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more possible implementation (without list duplication):

```
def optMin(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Option[Int] =
  (a, b) match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Option( x min y)
    case (sx, None)         => sx
    case (None, sy)         => sy
    case _                  => None
   }

li.reduceLeft { optMin(_, _) }
```

But for all comparison created Pair object.

Imho it is a struggle of code expression and code optimality.

Comment: Ok, exactly that piece of code I wanted to avoid because it looked so ugly :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `view` to prevent the creation of an intermediate list

```
li.view.flatten.reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
```

Comment: imho your example does the same when you force the evaluation?